# How do I set a location for an event in iOS Calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, geolocation, timezone

A date and time is incomplete without a location. How do I tell the iOS Calendar app where my event occurs, especially if the event does not have a street address that is resolvable by Apple Maps?

More detail: Right now I am physically located in Amsterdam, but I want to add some [Burning Man](http://burningman.com) events to my calendar. There are two levels of location at play here: the "street address" of the event within Black Rock City (say, ["Yurtopia, 9:30 & E"](http://www.burningman.com/preparation/maps/14_maps/)) and the location (hence timezone) of [Black Rock City itself](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Black+Rock+City,+NV,+USA/@40.7851743,-119.2077501,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x809fb834cedea63b:0xbeb0dbe188039187) (somewhere in the northern Nevada desert.)

What combination of Calendar settings, location field entry and anything else can I make while in Amsterdam that will remind me at half-past midday on Wednesday the 27th of August 2014, for the entry "Hexayurt Happy Hour, 1-4pm, Yurtopia, 9:30 & E, Black Rock City, Nevada", when I'm actually in Black Rock City?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is how to do it.

First thing to do is enable time zone support within Calendar. Open Settings, select "Mail, Contacts and Calendars". Find "Time Zone Support" under Calendars and turn it on. It should automatically set the timezone to your current location, that's fine.

Then create your event in Calendar. The only important fields for scheduling the event correctly are the time and the timezone. Location for example doesn't affect it. Just enter the correct time (13:00 - 16:00) and set the timezone to a nearby city iOS will recognise like Las Vegas. Once you click Done you should see the event in your calendar with the time automatically converted to the time in your current time zone.

Then once you are in the US you need to remember to manually set the Calendar timezone under "Mail, Contacts and Calendars" to Las Vegas or another city in the Pacific Standard Time timezone.

Then your events should appear with the correct time.